# Proof existence of $c$ so that $f(c)/g(c)\geq\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)w(x)dx/\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)w(x)dx$ for $f$, $g$, and $w$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I intuitively thought the following statement was true, but couldn't find anything about it online, so I tried to prove it.
Firstly, is the statement true in the first place? I.e. counterexample or reference to proof of (closely related) theorem
Secondly, does the general outline of my proof correct? If not, are there additional constraints that would make it hold?
Thirdly, it be strengthened so that $\hat x$ always exists (not infinite)?


Edit: I realized that, as the functions are symmetrical, I can probably change the possible range of $x_l$ and $x_u$ to $\mathbb{R^+}\cup \{ +\infty \}$ and keep the usefulness of the proof. This may help deal with some of the infinity issues.

(I know the the notation is not formally correct, however, I think the idea is clear)

---

#### Statement

Let $A$ be a class of functions for which $\forall a \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:$

- $a(x): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto a(x)$
- $a(-x) = a(x)$
- $a(x) \ge 0$
- $\frac{da(x)}{dx} \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{a(x)dx}\in \mathbb{R}$

$\forall f, g, w \in A, x_l, x_u \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}:$
 $\exists \hat x \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}:$
  $\frac{f(\hat x)}{g(\hat x)} \ge 
\frac
{\int_{x_l}^{x_u}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_l}^{x_u}{g(x)w(x)dx}}$

---

#### Proof

$\forall a_i, a_j \in \mathcal{A}: a_i\cdot a_j\in \mathcal{A}$

$\forall a_i \in \mathcal{A}: \exists A_i: \frac{dA_i(x)}{dx}=a_i$ and $A_i(x)$ increases monotonically

$\Rightarrow\forall x_l, x_u \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}: \exists c \in \mathbb{R} \text{ with } x_l \le c \le x_u:$
  
$\int_{x_l}^{x_u}{a_i(x)dx}=
\int_{x_l}^{c}{a_i(x)dx}+
\int_{c}^{x_u}{a_i(x)dx}$
   with 
   $\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_l}^{x_u}{a_i(x)dx}=\int_{x_l}^{c}{a_i(x)dx}=\int_{c}^{x_u}{a_i(x)dx}$


Thus $\forall f, g, w \in \mathcal{A}, \forall x_{l,i}, x_{u,i} \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}: \exists c_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ with } x_{l,i} \le c_i \le x_{u,i}):$

 $
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}}
=\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{f(x)w(x)dx} + \int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{g(x)w(x)dx} + \int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}} $
 with
  $
\frac{1}{2}
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx} = 
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{f(x)w(x)dx} = 
\int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}
$
  and with
  (1) $
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{g(x)w(x)dx} \le 
\frac{1}{2}
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx} \le 
\int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}
$ 
  $
\Rightarrow\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{g(x)w(x)dx}} \ge 
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}}
$
  or
  (2) $
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{c_i}{g(x)w(x)dx} \ge 
\frac{1}{2}
\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx} \ge 
\int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}
$ 
  $
\Rightarrow\frac
{\int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{c_i}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}} \ge 
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}}
$

If (1) let $x_{l,i+1}=x_{l,i}$ and let $x_{u,i+1}=c_i$. 
If (2) let $x_{l,i+1}=c_i    $ and let $x_{u,i+1}=x_{u,i}$.

Repeat the above process for $i = 0, 1, ..., n$.

A series of
$
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}} \geq
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i-1}}^{x_{u,i-1}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i-1}}^{x_{u,i-1}}{g(x)w(x)dx}} \geq
... \geq
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,0}}^{x_{u,0}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,0}}^{x_{u,0}}{g(x)w(x)dx}}
$
will emerge.
$lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} |x_{u,i}-x_{l,i}|$ diverges if either or both started out as $\frac{+}{-} \infty$ and remained $\frac{+}{-} \infty$, or converges to 0.

If it converges to 0, let $\hat x = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}x_{l,i}$, and then the limit of the above series is:
$
\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}
\frac
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(x)w(x)dx}}
{\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(x)w(x)dx}} =
\frac
{\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{f(\hat x)w(\hat x)dx}}
{\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{g(\hat x)w(\hat x)dx}} = 
\frac
{f(\hat x)w(\hat x)\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{dx}}
{g(\hat x)w(\hat x)\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{l,i}}^{x_{u,i}}{dx}} = 
\frac
{f(\hat x)w(\hat x)}
{g(\hat x)w(\hat x)} =
\frac{f(\hat x)}{g(\hat x)}
$